# Different choice of bases leads to a homeomorphic metric on Hom(V,W)

Tags: manifolds, differential

Let Hom(V,W) denote all linear transformations from V to W. Choosing a basis for V and W, we can identify Hom(V,M) with the m*n matrices, and consequently give it the metric of R^nm. Show that a different choice of bases leads to a homeomorphic metric on Hom(V,W)

Comment: The metric on $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ arises as a norm. Any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent (since the unit ball is compact).

Comment: Could you please write more details?

Answer (score 1):

1. The metric on $X = \mathbb{R}^{nm}$ arises as a norm.
   $$
   \|(x_j)\| = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{nm} |x_j|^2}
   $$
2. Any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent : Define a fixed norm on $X$ as
   $$
   \|(x_j)\|_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|
   $$
   Now, if $\|\cdot \|$ is any other norm on $X$, then
   $$
   \|x\| = \|\sum_{j=1}^n x_j e_j\| \leq M\|x\|_1
   $$
   where
   $$
   M = \max\{\|e_j\| : 1\leq j\leq n\}
   $$
   Hence, the identity map
   $$
   \iota : (X,\|\cdot\|_1) \to (X,\|\cdot\|)
   $$
   is continuous.
3. The unit ball
   $$
   B = \{x\in X : \|x\|_1 \leq 1\}
   $$
   is compact by [Bolzano-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)
   Hence the map $\iota$ restricted to the unit ball maps a compact set to another compact set and is hence a homeomorphism. In other words, $\iota^{-1}$ is a bounded linear map, and so there exists a $M'\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
   $$
   \|x\|_1 \leq M' \|x\|
   $$
   Thus, $\|\cdot \|$ and $\|\cdot \|_1$ are equivalent norms, and so generate the same topology.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is ej the basis for W?

Comment: No. A basis of $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$

Comment: Why can we just show the map can map a compact set to a compact set to get the homeomorphic conclusion?